# Spark 2.3.1 on YARN : how to monitor stages progress programatically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a setup with Spark running on YARN, and my goal is to programmatically get updates of the progress of a Spark job by its application id.

My first idea was to parse HTML output of the YARN GUI. However, the problem of such GUI, is that the progress bar associated to a spark job don't get updated regularly and even don't change most of time : when the job start, the percent is something like 10%, and it stuck to this value until the job finish. So such YARN progress bar is just irrelevant for Spark Jobs.

When I click to the Application Master link corresponding to a Spark Job, I'm redirected to the Spark GUI that is temporarily binded during the job run. The stages page is very relevant about progress of the Spark job. However it is plain HTML, so it is a pain to parse. On the Spark documentation, they talk about a JSON API, however it seems that I can't access to it as I'm under YARN and I'm accessing Spark GUI trough YARN proxy pages.

May be a solution, in order to have access to more things, could be to access to the real Spark GUI ip:port, and not the YARN proxied one, but I don't know if I can get such source URL easily...

All of that sound complicated to just get Spark job progress... As of 2018, could you please tell us what are the preferred methods to get relevant *stages progress* of a Spark Job running on YARN ?

Comment: YARN is basically a Resource Manager for batch jobs, and at high level, a batch job has no "progress" -- either it's running, or it has succeeded, or it has failed completely. Any intermediate failure may trigger a rewind/restart. On the other hand, if you want a live stream of what is happening to entertain your friends and family... You may set up a Flume instance, and configure a  Flume plug-in for Log4J so that your Spark logs are streamed somewhere. Then it's up to you to do sthg with that stream.

Comment: I have a light pipeline with almost no intermediate failure, so I absolutely do not share your analysis about batch progress only for friends and family. I also clearly  identified particular stages on Spark GUI that the progress are very relevant to show an overall progress to our customers. So if YARN is too high level, and if we are not debating about the relevance of monitoring batch progress, could you please provide information about retrieving relevant progress metrics from Spark GUI ?

Comment: do you want the progress within the spark application or as an external app? In the application itself, you could get these informations from the SparkSession

Comment: Raphael, I like very well both of your two solutions. Either getting relevant progress stats by an external app, knowing that Spark GUI in behind YARN. Or by registering some events function from the SparkSession inside my Spark app ! Could you please provide more details on how to do that as a new SO answer ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the application itself, you can get informations on stage progress by using `spark.sparkContext.statusTracker`, you can look how e.g. Zeppelin Notebook implemented a progress bar for Spark 2.3: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/spark-scala-parent/src/main/scala/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/JobProgressUtil.scala

Comment: The first really clever answer for my use case, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve YARN application state and other details for your submitted spark on yarn job via REST API

Refer to the below links:

https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html#Example_usage

https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API

Comment: Thank you Mansoor. However I prefer a solution based on Spark, even I'm running it under YARN. Because YARN APIs are irrelevant for getting a progress of stages, or an overall progress, for Spark Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

No way of knowing the progress in percentage, as you can have any amount of Spark stages. However, there is a REST API for Spark History Server  - [Monitoring and Instrumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) with which you can ask for stages/tasks/jobs info. Assuming your app has predefined amount of Stages - you can calculate the progress.

Comment: As said to Samson Scharfrichter, YES I have predefined / predictable stages, so calculating progress is highly relevant in my use case. So a solution is to calculate progress through statusTracker from inside (as said by Raphael), but query rest api of the Spark History is a good idea too. I however prefer the inside approach, because Spark History doesn't refresh information very well, even by tuning it a bit. Thank you anyway :)